# Filtering results on a lot of parameters

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm searching for a way to filter +- 100 weighted averages, for which I've already made the correct formula. The datasets are in 7 different tabs and contain +- 40 columns and on average +- 50 rows.

The filters should give me altered weighted averages by excluding rows that contain a certain value in one of its columns.

For each of the 100 averages, I should have +- 15 different 'versions' based on these filters.

This means that using FILTER or IF will take too many steps and a spreadsheet too slow to load. For FILTER, I would need to create 15 extra tabs per existing tab, which means a total of 105 tabs. Using IF, I would need more than the max of 4000 characters for each of the 100 formulas, or split the results in 2 or more tables, which I'd like to avoid.

In other words, I hope to find a way to skip certain of the steps I need for the FILTER or IF.

I added a simplified spreadsheet in the attachment to show the problem. Just bare in mind that the dataset is much bigger and the required number of parameters are much bigger as well.

[Sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pUVjRN4n_Tec_4FMxxqDu7Gh_OrVmBn4qbd_wPXOK6o/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Please share a test sheet with desired results